# React Native - Using ToolbarAndroid with Navigator's navigationBar

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native 0.14.0 to develop an Android application. Currently I'm using the `ToolbarAndroid` component to add a toolbar on top of my scene, but it is not kept between scenes. I found that the `Navigator` has a `navigationBar` property, which can be set to a `Navigator.NavigationBar` component, which should include an object dealing with the title and left and right buttons of the navigation bar. [See the official example to understand what I mean](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7da42e3950169b12c78a450ac83cbee8c9141dff/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigationBarSample.js#L146). As there is little documentation on this part, I have to rely on the example to set the `navigationBar` properly.

This `Navigator.NavigationBar` is not as powerful as the `ToolbarAndroid`, as itdoesn't automatically have space for the logo, for example.

Is there any way to use `ToolbarAndroid` with the `navigationBar` property of the `Navigator`?

Comment: Any update on this? What did you finally use?

Comment: @antoine129 I couldn't find a way and dropped it. They've released the new ExNavigator, I don't know if that would be possible with it.

Comment: Okay, in the end I created my own NavBar and customized it, and it returns a `<Navigator.NavigationBar ... {...this.props} />` so that I can feed it to `<Navigator />`. Works like a charm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. The closest you could probably get is to wrap the ToolbarAndroid in a component and map the navigator `left`, `right` methods to the `onIconClicked` functions. But that defeats the purpose as you are probably most interested in the ToolbarAndroid's UI.

You need to pass a component that will behave something like the [Navigator.NavigationBar](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBar.js#L180). If you can drop in a component that will play nice and provide some of the expected props then it'll work.